# How to dynamically bind data to label in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

How to dynamically bind data to label in Asp.net MVC. I have table where i need to display all compnay name dayanamically. I did create a Model for compnay name.

code in model look like this,

```
public class CompnayName
 {
     public string compnayName { get; set; }
     public string address { get; set; }

 }
```

Comment: what are you using as data source?

Comment: I am using SQL as data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please first correct spelling of the class name ;-)

Your asp page needs to inherit from your model:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<namespace.CompanyName>"
```

Then uses LabeFor:

```
<%= Html.LabelFor(m => Model.companyName)%>
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: `Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<namespace.CompanyName>"`

Comment: you gotta understand, it's not a company, it's a comp-Nay, dog!